# ggplot2: "Unknown parameters: probs" for fun.y = quantile in geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code for drawing a line of the 10% quantile produces an error "Unknown parameters: probs". Does anybody know why?

```
ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = cyl), data = mtcars) + 
geom_point(color = "orange") + 
geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, probs = 0.1)
```

I have updated to the newest version of ggplot and use the following R version:

> R.Version()
>
> $platform
>   [1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
>
> $arch
>   [1] "x86_64"
>
> $os
>   [1] "mingw32"
>
> $system
>   [1] "x86_64, mingw32"
>
> $status
>   [1] ""
>
> $major
>   [1] "3"
>
> $minor
>   [1] "2.0"
>
> $year
>   [1] "2015"
>
> $month
>   [1] "04"
>
> $day
>   [1] "16"
>
> $`svn rev`
>   [1] "68180"
>
> $language
>   [1] "R"
>
> $version.string
>   [1] "R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)"
>
> $nickname
>   [1] "Full of Ingredients"

Comment: Read `help("stat_summary")`. The ggplot2 update to version 2.0.0 has changed how you pass additional parameters to functions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It took me some digging through the ggplot2 2.0-helpfiles. For this case, they are [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html). In the new version there is an argument `fun.args`. So, I was able to run this code with an updated version of ggplot and produce the desired plot:

```
ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = cyl), data = mtcars) + 
  geom_point(color = "orange") + 
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = "quantile", fun.args=list(probs=0.1))
```